# How can I run GWT unit tests when using the google-charts API?

Tags: unit-testing, gwt, google-visualization

I am using the gwt-google-apis package in GWT so that I can use the visualization API. However, I cannot find a configuration that allows me to run unit tests that use DataTable. Does anyone have a working configuration where a GWT Unit Test uses elements from the visualization portion of the gwt-google-apis?

gwt-google-apis: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a project and I tried both the visualization api that lives in your GWT project and the HTTP based Google Charts API.  I liked the Google Charts API much better and it's pretty flexible and powerful.  Here's a short tutorial on using it with GWT:

http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2011/07/google-charts-api.html